# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str python

Tags: python, colors

this is my code

```
import time, random
import colorama
from colorama import Fore
colorama.init(autoreset=True)

while True:
    random = random.randint(0,100)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print(Fore.GREEN + random)
```

but i am getting an error:

```
print(Fore.GREEN + random)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

the meaning of this program is to output random numbers in the colour green

Comment: You mean `print(Fore.GREEN + str(random))` ?

Comment: Fore.GREEN + str(random)

Answer (score 1):

```py
import time, random
import colorama
from colorama import Fore
colorama.init(autoreset=True)

while True:
    random_num = random.randint(0,100)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print(Fore.GREEN + str(random_num))
```

You forgot to use `str` so what happend is that you tried to do: `str + int` which is not defiend.
Also, you named you random number variable `random` and overrided the `random` library.

Comment: random = random.randint(0,100)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'randint'             i get an error

Comment: That's right, its because you save the random number in a variable named random and by that overriding the library random. (FIXED)